# Virtual work (generalized forces) for rotation with Euler angles

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, rotational-dynamics, work

Here is what we know from virtual work:
\begin{equation}
\delta W=\sum_{i=1}^N{\vec F_i\cdot\delta\vec r_{i}}
\end{equation}
Where $N$ is the number of bodies in the system. I am considering a quadcopter, modeled as a rigid body so it is just one body and we have:
$$
\delta W=\vec F\cdot\delta\vec r
$$
My question concerns only rotational dynamics, so let's focus on just the torques. Let us rename $\vec F$ to $\vec M$ just to make it clear that we are talking about torques (moments):
$$
\delta W=\vec M \cdot \delta\vec r
$$
**Expressed in the quadcopter frame** (call it frame $B$), the moments exerted by the propellers on the quadcopter are, generally:
$$
\vec M=\begin{bmatrix}
\tau_x^B \\ \tau_y^B \\ \tau_z^B
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Because we are talking about moments, the "position" vector $\vec r$ actually holds the rotations *expressed in the same frame as $\vec M$*. Because I express $\vec M$ in the $B$ frame, I need to express the rotations in the $B$ frame. I am using the Tait-Bryan Euler angle convention. Starting from the inertial frame $I$ then:

1. **Yaw** by $\psi$ around $z_I$, the result is the $\{x',y',z'\}$ frame

   - Corresponding rotation matrix is $R_\psi$
2. **Pitch** by $\theta$ around $y'$, the result is the $\{x'',y'',z''\}$ frame

   - Corresponding rotation matrix is $R_\theta$
3. **Roll** by $\phi$ around $x''$, the result is the $\{x_B,y_B,z_B\}$ frame

   - Corresponding rotation matrix is $R_\phi$

You see that each Euler angle is in a different frame: $\psi$ is in the $I$ frame, $\theta$ is in the $(')$ frame and $\phi$ is in the $('')$ frame. From what I know, we transform between angular rates in the $B$ frame and the Euler angle time derivatives using:

$$
\omega=R_\phi\begin{bmatrix}\dot\phi\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}+
R_\phi R_\theta\begin{bmatrix}0\\\dot\theta\\0\end{bmatrix}+
R_\phi R_\theta R_\psi\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\\dot\psi\end{bmatrix}
$$

**However**, $\omega$ is **not integrable** (see sub-section 3.17 of http://people.mech.kuleuven.be/~bruyninc/tmp/HermanBruyninckx-robotics.pdf). Therefore angles in the body frame as such do not exist and I cannot simply write:

$$
\vec r=R_\phi\begin{bmatrix}\phi\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}+
R_\phi R_\theta\begin{bmatrix}0\\\theta\\0\end{bmatrix}+
R_\phi R_\theta R_\psi\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\\psi\end{bmatrix}
$$

Where $\vec r$ is our "position" vector in the virtual work equation containing three angles in the $B$ frame identifying the quad-copter's attitude. The end motivation is to apply the generalized force relation:
$$
Q_j=\sum_{i=1}^N{\vec F_i \cdot \frac{\partial \vec r_i}{\partial q_j}}
$$
Where $q_j$ are the generalized coordinates, for me these are:

- $q_1=\phi$
- $q_2=\theta$
- $q_3=\psi$

I really appreciate your help for my question: **find the expression for the generalized forces** $Q_j$ (well, generalized torque really in this case).

Comment: Did you mean $\dot{\omega}=$ or ${\omega}=$ ? Angular velocity is $\omega=f(\dot{\phi},\ldots)$ and angular acceleration is $\dot{\omega}=f(\dot{\phi},\ddot{\phi},\ldots)$

Comment: You are correct, the dot is wrong

Answer (score 1):

The velocity jacobian is $\vec{\omega}_B = J\, \dot{q}$ with $q=(\phi,\theta,\psi)$. This is used to transform between the generalized forces/torques $Q$ and the vector torques $\vec{M}_B=(\tau_x^B,\tau_y^B,\tau_z^B)$

$$ Q = J^\intercal \vec{M}_B $$

The power through the joint is

$$ Q \cdot \dot{q} = Q^\intercal \dot{q} = \left(J^\intercal \vec{M}_B\right)^\intercal \dot{q} = \vec{M}_B^\intercal J \dot{q} = \vec{M}_B^\intercal \vec{\omega} =\vec{M}_B \cdot \vec{\omega} \hphantom{MMM} \checkmark  $$

Comment: Thanks! Please elaborate (or point to a source) which shows how you obtain $Q=J^T \vec M_B$

Comment: Actually it comes from the power calculation. It is the unique value that maintains the powerflow through a joint. I also found it in slide 21 of http://www.diku.dk/OLD/undervisning/2005f/101/lecture11.pdf and slide 32 of http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~todorov/courses/amath533/FeatherstoneSlides.pdf

Comment: would you know how to derive it from virtual work?

Comment: Equation 7.2.31 in http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mechanical-engineering/2-12-introduction-to-robotics-fall-2005/lecture-notes/chapter7.pdf